# Dynamic Array with (1) Value - VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a quick question that I hope will be easy for anyone familiar with arrays to answer.

I've got a single column with a varying number of lists separated by a space. I have the program adding the numbers up. When it hits an empty cell, it should add that number to an array, increase the number of spaces in the array by (1) and, set the total counter back to zero, and skip to the next iteration of the loop its in and begin counting till it hits a space again. Over time there will be varying amounts of lists. I don't imagine that there will ever be more than 3-4, but I'd like to program it to handle it if there are more than that in the future.

So, for instance, cells C4:C10 contain numbers adding up to 200, then cell C11 is empty. Cells C12:C14 contain numbers adding up to 150. I'd like the array to store 200 in the first spot and 150 in the second spot. Then I'd like message boxes to pop up telling me "List 1 is 200", List 2 is 150", etc...

Right now, I'm getting subscript out of bounds, but I think it's because I didn't declare an array size. I'd like for it to be dynamic, but I didn't know how to have an array only contain (1) slot. It's always something like arr(0 to 1). I don't just see a single value in the examples I'm looking at and since it's in a for loop, if I did a loop for lbound to ubound, I think it would say something like "List 1 is 200", "List 2 is " with no value on the second one, because didn't have data if there is only one list.

I may be over thinking this or going about it the wrong way, but I've never really used arrays before. I think it will be helpful in this program. Thanks for any help you can provide.

I'm going to provide the mess I have below. I haven't cleaned this up and commented it well, yet, so you can ask if you have questions. I'm sure I'm doing it wrong, I'm just trying to give you an idea of where I'm going.

```
Private Sub cmdTest_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim intValue As Integer
    Dim strCell As String
    Dim arr() As Long
    Dim intArr As Integer

    Set wb = Application.Workbooks("ListTotal.xlsm")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Main")

    Call LastRowWithData_xlUp_1(lastColRow)

    MsgBox "Number of lists is: " & WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C3:C" & lastColRow), "") + 1

    Call FindLastRow(LastRow)

    'Count pages left in each series
    intValue = 0

    'set number of values in array
    intArr = 1

    For i = 3 To LastRow

            strCell = "C" & i

        If Range(strCell) = "" Then
            arr(0) = intValue
            intValue = 0
            GoTo NextIteration
        End If

                openingParen = InStr(Range(strCell), "[")
                closingParen = InStr(Range(strCell), "]")
                enclosedvalue = Mid(Range(strCell), openingParen + 1,              closingParen - openingParen - 1)
                intValue = intValue + enclosedvalue
                MsgBox "The number of pages in this book is: " & enclosedvalue

        NextIteration:
        MsgBox "The total pages left in the series is: " & intValue

    Next

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        MsgBox ("The number of pages left in Series " & j & " is:")  'arr(i))
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to size the array. You can achieve this by using `Redim`. Something like `Redim Arr(99)` would size a 1-dimensional array 100 empty elements. Did you want enough space for each row? If so, you can use LastRow, although I don't see where that is declared.

Comment: Hey Ryan. Yes, I did see how to resize it. I could use Redim Preserve Arr. I'm not saving each row. I'm totaling each list and saving the total in the array. The idea was that I could loop through the array and display each total. So if I had 3 lists, I could do a loop where I get the ubound of the array and say from j=1 to ubound, msgbox "The total is: " & arr(j).

Answer (score 0):

An approach I'd use is to store the data in a dictionary instead of an array.

Using a dictionary will be fast to perform lookups based on a key, and you can make the key almost whatever you want to uniquely identify the totals. This will likely (I think) be more symbolic and easy to understand than an index number in an array.

The sheet I've setup as a test (on Sheet1):

[image: Spreadsheet]

Here's the example code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    Dim myDict As Object: Set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim i As Long

    'Add data to a dictionary
    With myDict
        'the first parameter is a unique key that identifies the record
        'the second parameter is the value
        'Remember to change the range reference
        .Add "the Range A1:A5", WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("Sheet1!A1:A5"))
        .Add "the Range B1:B5", WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("Sheet1!B1:B5"))
        .Add "the Range C1:C5", WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("Sheet1!C1:C5"))
    End With

    'Iterate the dictionary and return the key and value
    For i = 0 To myDict.Count - 1
        Debug.Print "The sum is: " & myDict.items()(i) & " for Key: " & myDict.keys()(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Results in the Immediate Window:

```
The sum is: 6 for Key: the Range A1:A5
The sum is: 5 for Key: the Range B1:B5
The sum is: 12 for Key: the Range C1:C5
```

Comment: Ryan, my ranges are variable. The list lengths vary.

Comment: Ranges can be variables too.